# how to make a view stay on top alwayson all screens

Tags: java, kotlin

I have got display over other apps permission in android now how can I make a view that always stays on top and responses to clicks or some gestures

Answer (score 0):

I did this by getting the `window.decorView.rootView` and adding my inflated layout there.

```
// parent of activity,
val parent = (context as AppCompatActivity).window.decorView.rootView as? ViewGroup
// inflate view,
view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog, parent, false)

// add the view to the parent container,
parent?.addView(dialogView, params)
```

You can add onClick listeners to the inflated view and its children.

Comment: It's only displaying on top of app is their any way to on top of all screens